# How did Tia Dalma acquire Captain Barbossa's body?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

The final scene in ***Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest***, is the revelation of the resurrection of Captain Hector Barbossa via Tia Dalma's magic (presumably), as a lead into the next film.

[image: Monkey Jack]

Earlier in the film, viewers can see that **his body** is already there when Jack and crew visit her, as Barbossa's undead monkey sits next to and touches his boots, while the rest of his body remains hidden. Also Gibbs mentions that,

> "What with the Isla de Muerta going all pear-shaped, reclaimed by the
>   sea and the treasure with it."

With the Isle de Muerta being taken back by the sea, **how could Tia Dalma acquire, retrieve, or procure Barbossa's body?** Is this ever explained in any other source material or trivia info?

I imagine it could somehow relate to the monkey being undead (steal gold piece?) and Tia Dalma being the sea Goddess Calypso (the briefly mentioned hurricane?), but I have never found a **real explanation** with what was happening with these things.

Comment: Is it possible to her to visit Isla de muerta and retrieve body herself? being a goddess and having some mystical powers other than that, It seems she is capable of such a task. May be the hurricane was her doing to destroy any evidance

Comment: It might very well be, but again I'm looking for proof of methodology.